# How to resolve "Cannot resolve method 'Insertdata'" in Java?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, crud, lang

I'm try to insert data to SQLite. But something are wrong in AddActivity.java. My concept is insert data to SQLite. After read data from data show list.

When click list on data list it will be show detail of this list.

[image: Click here to see a picture.]

Here is the error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'Insertdata(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)'
```

myDBClass.java

```java
package com.example.puen.projectdemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class myDBClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase";

    // Table Name
    private static final String TABLE_MEMBER = "members";

    public myDBClass(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Create Table Name
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEMBER +
                "(MemberID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                " Name TEXT(100)," +
                " Tel TEXT(100));");

        Log.d("CREATE TABLE", "Create Table Successfully.");
    }


    // Select Data
    public String[] SelectData(String strMemberID) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            String arrData[] = null;

            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Read Data

            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_MEMBER, new String[]{"*"},
                    "MemberID=?",
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(strMemberID)}, null, null, null, null);

            if(cursor != null)
            {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    arrData = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()];
                    /***
                     *  0 = MemberID
                     *  1 = Name
                     *  2 = Tel
                     */
                    arrData[0] = cursor.getString(0);
                    arrData[1] = cursor.getString(1);
                    arrData[2] = cursor.getString(2);
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return arrData;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

    }

    // Show All Data
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> SelectAllData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<>();
            HashMap<String, String> map;

            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // Read Data

            String strSQL = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MEMBER;
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(strSQL, null);

            if(cursor != null)
            {
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        map = new HashMap<>();
                        map.put("MemberID", cursor.getString(0));
                        map.put("Name", cursor.getString(1));
                        map.put("Tel", cursor.getString(2));
                        MyArrList.add(map);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
            return MyArrList;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEMBER);

        // Re Create on method  onCreate
        onCreate(db);
    }


}
```

AddActivity.java

```java
package com.example.puen.projectdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AddActivity extends Activity  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);


        // btnSave (Save)
        final Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // If Save Complete
                if(SaveData())
                {
                    // Open Form Main
                    Intent newActivity = new Intent(AddActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(newActivity);
                }
            }
        });


        // btnCancel (Cancel)
        final Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Open Form Main
                Intent newActivity = new Intent(AddActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(newActivity);
            }
        });

    }

    public boolean SaveData()
    {
        // txtMemberID, txtName, txtTel
        final EditText tMemberID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMemberID);
        final EditText tName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        final EditText tTel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtTel);

        // Dialog
        final AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AlertDialog ad = adb.create();

        // Check MemberID
        if(tMemberID.getText().length() == 0)
        {
            ad.setMessage("Please input [MemberID] ");
            ad.show();
            tMemberID.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }

        // Check Name
        if(tName.getText().length() == 0)
        {
            ad.setMessage("Please input [Name] ");
            ad.show();
            tName.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }

        // Check Tel
        if(tTel.getText().length() == 0)
        {
            ad.setMessage("Please input [Tel] ");
            ad.show();
            tTel.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }

        // new Class DB
        final myDBClass myDb = new myDBClass(this);

        // Check Data (MemberID exists)
        String arrData[] = myDb.SelectData(tMemberID.getText().toString());
        if(arrData != null)
        {
            ad.setMessage("MemberID already exists!  ");
            ad.show();
            tMemberID.requestFocus();
            return false;
        }

        // Save Data
        long saveStatus = myDb.InsertData(tMemberID.getText().toString(),
                tName.getText().toString(),
                tTel.getText().toString());
        if(saveStatus <=  0)
        {
            ad.setMessage("Error!! ");
            ad.show();
            return false;
        }

        Toast.makeText(AddActivity.this,"Add Data Successfully. ",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;
    }

}
```

DetailActivity.java

```java
package com.example.puen.projectdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailActivity extends Activity  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        // Read var from Intent
        Intent intent= getIntent();
        String MemID = intent.getStringExtra("MemID");

        // Show Data
        ShowData(MemID);

        // btnCancel (Cancel)
        final Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Open Form Show
                Intent newActivity = new Intent(DetailActivity.this,ShowActivity.class);
                startActivity(newActivity);
            }
        });

    }

    public void ShowData(String MemID)
    {
        // txtMemberID, txtName, txtTel
        final TextView tMemberID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMemberID);
        final TextView tName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        final TextView tTel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTel);

        // new Class DB
        final myDBClass myDb = new myDBClass(this);

        // Show Data
        String arrData[] = myDb.SelectData(MemID);
        if(arrData != null)
        {
            tMemberID.setText(arrData[0]);
            tName.setText(arrData[1]);
            tTel.setText(arrData[2]);
        }

    }

}
```

ShowActivity.java

```java
package com.example.puen.projectdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ShowActivity extends Activity  {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);

        final myDBClass myDb = new myDBClass(this);
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MebmerList = myDb.SelectAllData();

        // listView1
        ListView lisView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        SimpleAdapter sAdap;
        sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(ShowActivity.this, MebmerList, R.layout.activity_column,
                new String[] {"MemberID", "Name", "Tel"}, new int[] {R.id.ColMemberID, R.id.ColName, R.id.ColTel});
        lisView1.setAdapter(sAdap);

        lisView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int position, long mylng) {

                // Show on new activity
                Intent newActivity = new Intent(ShowActivity.this,DetailActivity.class);
                newActivity.putExtra("MemID", MebmerList.get(position).get("MemberID").toString());
                startActivity(newActivity);

            }
        });


        // btnCancel (Cancel)
        final Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Open Form Main
                Intent newActivity = new Intent(ShowActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(newActivity);
            }
        });

    }


}
```

Comment: where is InsertData method in `myDBClass` class??

Comment: correct question specially the title: it should describe problem shortly and NO BEGGING! Otherwise your question soon will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such method as "InsertData" in the class "myDBClass". You should add the method InsertData to the myDBClass, and add the logic to insert to the database in that method.

Comment: Thank you brother.
Something wrong is be myself. :(

Comment: Dont worry. Everybody does mistakes. Experts makes more silly mistakes than amateurs. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no Insertdata method in your myDBClass. You are calling something you haven't initialized.

Comment: Thank you so much.